# Why is the Program not printing Fibonacci Series?

Tags: python

I have written two version of the program and new to python. I am not able to understand what went wrong while printing a Fibonacci series. The first program prints the Fibonacci series correctly but the second program has an issue. Please let me know what's wrong.

**Program 1**

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

# Now call the function we just defined:
fib(2000)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
```

**Program 2**

```
# Let make a function that prints a Fibonacci 
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=" ")
        a = b
        b = a+b
fib(2000)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
```

Comment: There are print statement inside the method.... in the while section. And its working for me on IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is in the line:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

This assigns the value of `b` to `a` and assigns the value of `a+b` to `b`, but it does so before `a` is assigned its new value.

You replaced this with:

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

This changes `a` first and only then assigns `a+b` to `b`. If you'd want to do it like this you could do:

```
c = a+b
a = b
b = c
```

Or something similar, but I think the original solution is the cleaner one, although clearly not sufficiently intuitive, as it stumped you :)

Comment: Got your point. Seems  I was not able to catch the concept. Do you have some link pointing to this concept.

Comment: I don't have a specific link, but the concept is called 'tuple assignment' and it is often used to do tricks like swapping the values of two variables: `a, b = b, a`. Note how that's different from `a = b` and then `b = a`. Clearly, in the latter case, you'd end up with both variables having the same value. Note that your code combines 'tuple assignment' and Python's automatic unpacking of a tuple when required (so, it is unpacking the tuple that's created on the right, storing the components in the two variables on the left).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

is not the same as

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

In the first version: 
when first line is executed the old value of `a` is destroyed 
so the second line is equivalent to `b = b+b`

so at every iteration b is assigned to 2*b, hence the sequence 1,2,4,8...

Comment: Can you explain or provide a link?

Comment: sure no problem. edited!

Answer (score 0):

`a, b = b, a+b` is not the same as `a = b; b = a+b`.  In particular the value of `a` is not the same when `a+b` is evaluated.